# Rspec fails to run because of initialized constant in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activeadmin

So I'm trying to run rspec tests with

$ rspec spec/models

but I get this error

> /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/app/admin/admin_user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant AdminUser (NameError)
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/backports-2.6.7/lib/backports/tools.rb:314:in`require'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/backports-2.6.7/lib/backports/tools.rb:314:in `require_with_backports'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:230:in`block in constantize'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in `each'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:229:in`constantize'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise.rb:256:in `get'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:77:in`to'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in `modules'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:89:in`routes'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:156:in `default_used_route'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/mapping.rb:66:in`initialize'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise.rb:290:in `new'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise.rb:290:in`add_mapping'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:208:in `block in devise_for'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in`each'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/devise-2.1.3/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:207:in `devise_for'
>       from /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/config/routes.rb:41:in`block in '
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `instance_exec'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in`eval_block'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:267:in `draw'
>       from /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/config/routes.rb:1:in`'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`each'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in`reload!'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:108:in `reload_routes!'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in`reload!'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activeadmin-0.6.0/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:61:in `block in attach!'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in`*run*_191199301_*prepare*_874569490__callbacks'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in`_run_prepare_callbacks'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in`prepare!'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47:in`block in '
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`run'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`each'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in`initialize!'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
>       from /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
>       from /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in `require'
>       from /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/spec/spec_helper.rb:3:in`'
>       from /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/spec/models/delivery_spec.rb:1:in `require'
>       from /home/kenny/WorkSpace/FeedingForward/spec/models/delivery_spec.rb:1:in`'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `load'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in`block in load_spec_files'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in `each'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:789:in`load_spec_files'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in`run'
>       from /home/kenny/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p362/gems/rspec-core-2.12.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'

Here is the code in admin_user in the admin directory

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do     
  index do                            
    column :email
    column :primary_phone
```

I also have a admin_user class in the models directory

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :init

  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :primary_phone, :password, :password_confirmation,    :remember_me, :notify_by_sms, :notify_by_email
  # attr_accessible :title, :body

  protected

  def init
    self.notify_by_sms ||= false
    self.notify_by_email ||= true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the schema is missing from your test database. Make sure you run the migrations for your test environment too.

```
RAILS_ENV=test be rake db:migrate
```